# I am running Windows 8.1 on a Samsung Ativ Book 9 Plus and, I think, hotkeys (or similar) will activate on it's own.

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

Often the keyboard will develop a mind of it's own, ie; when I type 's' the charms menu will pop out with the search window open.  There are many examples. I need to know a: how to turn this off, b: what is this function called? I've been having to restart my ultrabook so I can type as normal.  Very frustrating!!!

As you can probably tell, I am a bit of a novice. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the window you want to type in has focus (is selected)?

Comment: I think so. But now that you mention it, I have noticed it happening recently when I try to type search criteria into the small google search window to the right of the address bar. I know in those cases I have definitely ensured the cursor is actively in the search bar.

Comment: A common problem with laptops is that you accidently touch the clickpad while typing which causes the window to lose focus. Maybe you can look into your driver settings to see if there is an option to disable the clickpad while typing (with an added delay).

Comment: I'll look into disabling the touchpad whilst typing but I usually discover the problem when I start to type and the touchpad is not involved. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just to be sure, you could hook up an external keyboard and see if you still get the problem. If the problem persists, it might be a software problem (probably fixed by reinstall), or a hardware problem where the clickpad registers a touch when there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Windows key and "S" at the same time will open the Windows 8 search charm thingie.  You're probably pressing the Windows key with your wrist or another finger, or the keyboard has a flaw like pressing S make it appear as if the Windows key gets pressed too.

Can you try using a USB keyboard to rule out physical problems with your keyboard?

Comment: It definitely does not only happen when I hit 's' but with a variety of keys that work fine otherwise. My guess is that it is some kind of time-saving function that has somehow kicked in, but I have no idea what it is called (so I can investigate it) or how to disable it.